# Trigger on SQL Server DB to insert/update a table as soon as parent table is updated or inserted

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am new to trigger writing.I wrote a trigger to Insert/update a table as soon as record in the code/mother table is affected, i.e if if I am inserting a record for 1st time, it should insert that record with other related information in the new table . Same is applied for update also..Below is the code piece I tried,But its not working means even thogh it compiled successfully ..it is unable to insert record into the target table.. Here TQA_USER_ASSESSMENT is the core table and TQA_USER_ASSESSMENT should get populated /updated as per data in TQA_USER_ASSESSMENT.

```
               CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_RAM_DETAILS_GMAS] ON [dbo].[TQA_USER_ASSESSMENT]           FOR                 INSERT,UPDATE
               AS
              SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON

           --Ignore zero row updates, inserts
              IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN;

INSERT INTO TQA_RAM_DETAILS_GMAS
SELECT
        tu.name AS User_Name,
        tat.assessmentType AS Assessment_Type,
        tb.name AS Business_Class_Name,
        tr.name AS Region_Name,
        tc.name AS Country_Name,
        tf.facilityName AS Terminal_Name, 
        I.ovr_terminal_rating AS Terminal_Rating,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.dateOfInspection, 103) AS Date_of_Inspection, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.dateNextInspectionDue, 103) AS Expiry_date_of_rating,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), I.summ_lastUpdated, 103) AS lastUpdated





FROM
   INSERTED I INNER JOIN
        dbo.TQA_USERS tu ON I.userID=tu.userID INNER JOIN
        dbo.TQA_ASSESSMENT_TYPE AS tat ON tat.assessmentTypeID = I.assessmentTypeID INNER JOIN
        dbo.TQA_FACILITIES AS tf ON tf.facilityID = I.facilityID INNER JOIN
        dbo.TQA_ACCESS ta ON ta.facilityID=tf.facilityID INNER JOIN
        dbo.TQA_BUSINESS_CLASSES tb ON tb.businessClassID= ta.businessClassID INNER JOIN
        dbo.TQA_REGIONS tr ON tr.regionID= ta.regionID INNER JOIN
        dbo.TQA_COUNTRIES tc ON tc.countryID= ta.countryID
```

Comment: "its not working." is never a helpful diagnostic to give people you're asking for help from. In what **way** is it not working - producing an error? What error? Producing wrong results? What were your *expected* results, and (given we don't have your tables and data), what are the *actual* results? Also, the early exit for 0 rows in `inserted` is  pointless, given that it will just produce a 0 row insert anyway.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: It got executed successfully, but I cant see any record inserted in the target table

Comment: Then check your assumptions. That's a lot of inner joins in that query - if any one of those joins fails, you'll produce a zero row insert.

Answer (score 0):

**

> Execute this query in sql and troubleshoot ur trigger

**

```
SELECT
        tu.name AS User_Name,
        tat.assessmentType AS Assessment_Type,
        tb.name AS Business_Class_Name,
        tr.name AS Region_Name,
        tc.name AS Country_Name,
        tf.facilityName AS Terminal_Name, 
        myparentTable.ovr_terminal_rating AS Terminal_Rating,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), myparentTable.dateOfInspection, 103) AS Date_of_Inspection, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), myparentTable.dateNextInspectionDue, 103) AS Expiry_date_of_rating,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), myparentTable.summ_lastUpdated, 103) AS lastUpdated

     from  TQA_USER_ASSESSMENT myParentTable   INNER JOIN
            dbo.TQA_USERS tu ON myParentTable.userID=tu.userID INNER JOIN
            dbo.TQA_ASSESSMENT_TYPE AS tat ON tat.assessmentTypeID = myParentTable.assessmentTypeID INNER JOIN
            dbo.TQA_FACILITIES AS tf ON tf.facilityID = myParentTable.facilityID INNER JOIN
            dbo.TQA_ACCESS ta ON ta.facilityID=tf.facilityID INNER JOIN
            dbo.TQA_BUSINESS_CLASSES tb ON tb.businessClassID= ta.businessClassID INNER JOIN
            dbo.TQA_REGIONS tr ON tr.regionID= ta.regionID INNER JOIN
            dbo.TQA_COUNTRIES tc ON tc.countryID= ta.countryID
        where 
        myParentTable.assessmentTypeID = 'whatever u added'
    and myParentTable.userID='whatever u added'
    and myParentTable.facilityID = 'whatever u added'
```